# How can i find a shortcut for a program and running the exe file in the shortcut?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

On my pc the shortcut is in this location

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\OpenGrADS 2.0

But i'm not sure if this is for every windows i'm using windows 8.1 pro but not sure if when someone will install this program on windows 7 or any other os it will put it in the same location.

Second in this directory i have a shortcut file: GrADS Prompt and inside the file the shortcut in the properties i see: C:\OpenGrADS\Contents\Cygwin\Versions\2.0.2.oga.2\i686\opengrads.exe

In my program i did:

```
string exepath = @"C:\OpenGrADS\Contents\Cygwin\Versions\2.0.2.oga.2\i686\opengrads.exe";
```

But i'm not sure if anyone else installed the program to this location that's why i want to find the shortcut and then to run the exe inside the short cut file properties.

Or maybe in the constructor or adding a button to the designer to check if the file not exist then open a filebroswer:

```
if (!File.Exists(exepath))
            {

            }
```

Using this logic is better so the user will browse alone to the file location ?

Comment: How do you deploy your application to users?Using a setup file?

Comment: You could dive into registry to check out where the installed program is located, but I think the best option for you would be to allow users to set their own path in case the default one is not found.

Comment: If the executable will always be in the same place regardless of the directory the user selects for installation.  IE X:\USERCHOICE\Contents\etc...\opengrads.exe, then you should be able to use 'Environment.CurrentDirectory' to get the path.  -Edit, I understand your question better now.  You should check for the existence of the executable at a couple of known locations, and if it isn't found, have the user point to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my application where I require 3rd party programs to be installed I create options form in which I allow users to set the required paths and then I store all of required data in [Application Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750(v=vs.110).aspx)